# React memory leak on navigate after fetch promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory, frameworks

I have this issue:

`Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`

What i'm exactly doing.

```js
fetch(url, { signal }).then( ... ).finally(()=> navigate(`/blog/${query}`)
```

The signal comes from `AbortController` and it was recommenced by Jake Archibald here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/abortable-fetch, but it does not help at all. Can anybody tell me what is wrong? Assuming that state change before route and here's a problem. But how to add some params to URL without changing the route, navigating to it?

Comment: Where are you calling the fetch? This pretty much means that after you navigate away from the component (that is calling the fetch) you are still calling some changes/setState. Just ensure after the fetch is complete nothing in the component calls for state changes.

Comment: You usually see this when some async code calls `setState` after the component has already been unmounted. Make sure that your component doesn't unmount until your async code completes or cancel any ongoing operation during unmount. It depends on the use case. Please also show us the component code.